# UPDATE em uma query com multiplas entradas

Tags: c#, sql

Tenho um query onde eu tenho um SELECT a partir de um ID de um cliente, e um ID de um pedido. Posteriormente eu realizo um UPDATE em uma tabela, mudando a taxa de imposto sobre o pedido selecionado.

O problema é que um cliente pode ter vários pedidos. Quando eu coloco vários ID's de pedidos.... Mas como eu posso, de fato, fazer uma query pra fazer o UPDATE dessas múltiplas entradas?

Aqui eu tenho o SELECT:

```
SELECT
  p.idPedido,
  c.nome,
  p.dataPagamento,
  p.valor,
  p.taxaImposto
FROM
  Pedidos p
JOIN Clientes c ON (c.id = p.idCliente)
WHERE
  c.id IN ({txtClienteId.Text})
AND
  p.idPedido IN ({txtPedidoId.Text})
```

E aqui o UPDATE:

```
UPDATE
  Pedidos
SET
  taxaImposto = @taxa
WHERE
  idPedido = @idPedido
AND
  idCliente = @idCliente;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@taxa", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxaImposto.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idPedido", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtPedidoId.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idCliente", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text);
```

O UPDATE funciona normalmente quando tenho apenas uma entrada no ID de Pedidos, mas eu quero tornar possível fazer esse update pra várias entradas, de um mesmo cliente, ou seja, inserir um ID de cliente, uma Taxa, e n ID's de Pedidos.

Comment: Todos os registos do intervalo `WHERE c.id IN ({txtClienteId.Text}) AND p.idPedido IN ({txtPedidoId.Text})` vão ter a mesma taxa?

Comment: Sim, a taxa vai ser a mesma pra todos os pedidos selecionados

Comment: Existe seleção de clientes e/ou pedidos para fazer o `UPDATE`? Ou todos que foram devolvidos pelo `SELECT` serão atualizados?

Comment: O usuário vai inserir o ID do cliente, a taxa, e 1 ou vários pedidos, sendo que os pedidos sempre serão referentes ao mesmo cliente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendo em conta a informação na questão e comentários, talvez desta forma consiga resolver o problema:

```
string strSql = string.Format(@"
                UPDATE  Pedidos
                SET     taxaImposto = @taxa
                WHERE   idPedido    IN ({0})
                    AND idCliente   = @idCliente", txtPedidoId.Text);

// A variável "strSql" será utilizada para criar o "SqlCommand"

cmd.Parameters.Add("@taxa", SqlDbType.Float).Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtTaxaImposto.Text);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@idCliente", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtClienteId.Text);
```

Basicamente, o `UPDATE` será executado para um cliente específico (visto que indicou que o `ID` do cliente é indicado e os pedidos serão para esse mesmo cliente) mas para vários pedidos (aqueles indicados em `txtPedidoId.Text`).

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado pela solução João!

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, vc está realizando o update e o select separadamente, para realizar todos os updates ao mesmo tempo vc poderia realizar o update e o select em uma unica query

```
UPDATE
  Pedidos
SET
  Pedidos.taxaImposto = {txtTaxaImposto.Text}
FROM
  Pedidos p
  INNER JOIN Clientes c ON (c.id = p.idCliente)
WHERE
  c.id IN ({txtClienteId.Text})
AND
  p.idPedido IN ({txtPedidoId.Text})
```

Neste caso vc poderá colocar a lista de pedidos no campo `{txtPedidoId.Text}` e ele seria responsável por atualizar todos os pedidos nesta lista.

Comment: Na verdade, o processo esta sendo feito em duas partes. Um botão INICIAR, que faz o SELECT e exibe os dados da tabela na tela, e um segundo botão EXECUTAR, que, de fato, realiza o UPDATE. Por esse motivo eles estão separados...

Comment: O problema acontece quando eu coloco mais de 1 pedido, seja  por exemplo a textbox preenchida com 10, 15, 22.
Quando tenho apenas o 10, ele funciona normalmente, mas quando tem mais de uma entrada, ele retorna um erro.